# AWS S3 Execute Command Doesn't Seem To Work

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using `AWS PHP library` trying to perform a batch copy operation using `getCommand`. To do so I'm using the example they provided [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingPHP.html).

However, it doesn't seem to work and the worse part is, it does not throw any exception. I'm using other AWS services and they all throw exceptions in case of error. I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong here or if there is a way to catch these sort of exceptions.

Here is my code:

**Prepare**

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $batch[] = $s3->getCommand('CopyObject', array(
        'Bucket'             => $bucket,
        'Key'                => "{$i}-{$file}",
        'CopySource'         => "{$bucket}/{$file}"
    ));
}
```

**Execute**

```
try {
    // goes here
    echo __line__;
    $res =$s3->execute($batch);
    // not here
    echo __line__;
    return true;
} catch (\Aws\Exception\AwsException $e) {
    // not here
    echo __line__;
    $this->logger($e->getMessage());
    return false;
}
```

In order to catch the exception I also tried with: `\Guzzle\Service\Exception\CommandTransferException $e)` namespace and got no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end I solved this problem using `CommandPool::batch` function from AWS library.

For people with the same issue here is how  to use it:

**Prepare**

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $batch[] = $s3->getCommand('CopyObject', array(
        'Bucket'             => $bucket,
        'Key'                => "{$i}-{$file}",
        'CopySource'         => "{$bucket}/{$file}"
    ));
}
```

**Execute**

```
$results = CommandPool::batch($s3, $batch);
```

P.S. Don't forget to include `CommandPool` namespace:

```
use Aws\CommandPool;
```